# Network policy to deny traffic from a particular namespace

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

So let's say I have 5 namespaces - prod, preprod, uat, dev, and test. Each namespace have a different label - ns=prod, ns=preprod, ns=uat, ns=dev, and ns=test.

Question:
So I want to create a network policy where, I don't want to send traffic (egress) from ns=test to a particular namespace whose label is ns=prod. But ns=test should able to do egress to all other namespace.

Documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/

I tried to create a manifest file from the above documentation but had no luck. I'm able to do this using podSelector (labels of pods, but not using only namespaces as a whole).

Comment: yes @Jonas. As I said podSelector was working for me. Can you share a snippet?

Comment: what CNI are you using?

Comment: I'm using Weave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier if you could add the code snippet. However, it's not that tough to figure out what is going wrong.

I am thinking something like this might be the issue with your network policy. Your pods might be requiring world wide web connection, so you cannot stop comms from test to prod through `egress` rule as you might be adding `0.0.0.0/0` to let your pods on any env to communicate to outer world to download external libraries or whatever stuff associated with your application.

Due to this it is slightly difficult to add the `egress` rule to stop comms to any env. But on the contrary you can add `igress` rule to prod ns to not let communications from `test` or `dev`. Something like this might work, but again, we can change it based on needs.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: prod-network-policy
  namespace: prod
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      ns: prod
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          ns: prod
          ns: dev
          ns: uat
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          ns: prod
          ns: dev
          ns: uat
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.1.101/32 #Assuming allow incoming request from ingress controller
  egress:
  - to: []
```

There are several ways one can achieve this. But, I also sometimes refers to these example recipes on [Github](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubernetes-network-policy-recipes).

**Edit based on comment**
Addition of other namespaces to ingress rule to allow traffic from other namespaces except test.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Your solution will allow ingress from only prod namespace, but I want to allow traffic from all the other namespace except test.

Comment: Updated the answer, it's just you need to add whatever namespace you want to allow traffic from.

Comment: This solution has one problem, suppose I have many ns. So, there is no way to deny only one namespace when you have multiple ns. I have to specify each and everyone of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: network-policy-example
  namespace: test
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      ns: test
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          ns: preprod
          ns: uat
          ns: dev
          ns: test
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
```

...which will prevent any pod in the namespace `test` and with labels `ns=test` to talk to anyone except pods in the namespaces listed under `matchlabels`.

You could also do the other way around; to create a `NetworkPolicy` in the namespace `prod` and cut off ingress traffic of the pods with label `ns=prod`. Same result.

Note: You need `NetworkPolicy` controller, as it is no in the binaries of kubernetes.

Comment: This solution has one problem, suppose I have many ns. So, there is no way to deny only one namespace when you have multiple ns. @suren

Comment: Nope. With `NetworkPolicies` you first deny it all (with `policyTypes`), then start opening with `ingress` or `egress`. May be you could give them all the same label (e.g. `allowed=true`) and use `podSelector`, instead of `namespaceSelector`.

Comment: I'm able to do this using `podSelector`. I have mentioned this in question.